# PIC32 read feedback from UART

Tags: pic, communication, c, uart, wifi

I'm using a PIC32MX795F512H to set up a Roving RN-131 wifi module using UART.

I can communicate with the device but I want some feedback whether my commands are processed or not.

I basically need to check a string the WiFi module returns. The first time I check, it works, the second time, it's not doing anything anymore.

```
int connected()
{
    char receiverbuffer[50];
    char CMD[] = "CMD";
    char AOK[] = "AOK";
    int done = 0;
    int connected = 0;
    char str[250];
    putsUART1("$$$");
    memset(str,0,250*sizeof(char));
    memset(receiverbuffer,0,50*sizeof(char));
    while(!done)
    {
        while(U1STAbits.URXDA)
        {
            getsUART1(50, receiverbuffer, 123);
            U1STAbits.URXDA = 0;
            U1STAbits.OERR = 0;
            sprintf(str, "%s%s", str, receiverbuffer);
            memset(receiverbuffer,0,50*sizeof(char));   //Clears the buffer
        }
        if(!strcmp(str,CMD))
        {
            LATBbits.LATB7 = ~LATBbits.LATB7;
            done = 1;
            strcpy(str, "");
            memset(str,0,250*sizeof(char));
        }
    }
    done = 0;
    putsUART1("show con\r\n");
    while(!done)
    {
        while(U1STAbits.URXDA)
        {
            getsUART1(50, receiverbuffer, 123);
            U1STAbits.URXDA = 0;
            U1STAbits.OERR = 0;
            sprintf(str, "%s%s", str, receiverbuffer);
            memset(receiverbuffer,0,50*sizeof(char));   //Clears the buffer
        }
        if(!strcmp(str, CMD))
        {
            LATBbits.LATB7 = ~LATBbits.LATB7;
            done = 1;
            connected = 1;
            memset(str,0,250*sizeof(char));
        }
    }
    putsUART1("exit\r\n");

    return connected;
}
```

Any help would be welcome. I think I'm not clearing the string correctly but I have no idea why.

Comment: One thing I have found very useful in diagnosing problems like this is to connect the transmit (TX) line of the device you are talking to, to the RX lead of a logic level to RS-232 shifter, like [this one](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/449) from SparkFun and monitor the output with a terminal program like RealTerm on your PC.  This let's you see exactly what is coming back from the device.  You can also connect the shifter to the TX lead of the PIC32 to verify you are sending out what you think you are.

Comment: Right now, I'm debugging it that way. I know what the Wifi chip answers so I'm just sending it myself to debug using RealTerm